# Create JavaScript Array within For Loop

Tags: javascript

I want to create the array below with a for loop as its large

```
var centres = {
    1979: { x: width * 1 / 41, y: height / 2 },
    1980: { x: width * 2 / 41, y: height / 2 },
    1981: { x: width * 3 / 41, y: height / 2 },
    ...
}
```

and then access it as follows:

```
function nodeYearPos(d) {
   return yearCenters[d.year].x;
}
```

I have the following code, but its only setting the year...

```
  var yearCenters = Array.from(new Array(2020-1919+1), (x, i) => i + 1919);
  for (year = 1919; year <= 2020; year++) {
    coords = getCentres(year); // this returns an object in the form {x : x, y : y}
    yearCenters[year] = coords;
  }
```

Comment: use an object, not an array. arrays are 0-indexed

Comment: `yearCenters = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(new Array(2020-1919+1), (x, i) => [i + 1919,null]));` convert the array to object and then set values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do as gorak commented but with the getCenters function

```
var yearCenters = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(new Array(2020-1919+1), (x, i) => [i + 1919, getCenters(i + 1919)]));
```

or you can also try

```
var yearCenters = {};
for (year = 1919; year <= 2020; year++) {
  coords = getCenters(year);
  yearCenters[year] = coords;
}
```

Comment: I used the latter suggestion as this is nice and clear with its creation of an empty object ({}) and then populating it.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to fetch by year in `yearCenters` array (e.g. `yearCenters[year]`) this won't work since the year is not the index in the array.

I would suggest you first convert the array into a JS object so that indexing on it works with years.

See below snippet -

```js
// Create obejct from array
var yearCenters = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(new Array(2020-1919+1), (x, i) => [i + 1919, null]))
     
// This loop remains same
for (year = 1919; year <= 2020; year++) {
    coords = getCentres(year); // this returns an object in the form {x : x, y : y}
    yearCenters[year] = coords; 
}

// Mock function
function getCentres(year) {
  return {
    x: Math.random() * 100,
    y: Math.random() * 100
  }
}

console.log(yearCenters)
```